# Use appropriate formula by range in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, opencart

I have to count prices using different formula using price range as a float.

**For example**:

if `price` is lower than `100` use first option;

if `price` is between `100-300` use the second option, etc.

Here is some PHP code I am try to use:

```
if ($price <=100)
{
    $pricecount=(float)$price*1.25+25;
}
if ($price >100 && $price <=300)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.25+20;
}
if ($price >200 && $price <=600)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.2+20;
}
if ($price >600 && $price <=1000)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.2;
}
else
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.15;
}
```

Now only second formula is used. How to do it appropriatly?

Comment: What are your inputs ?

Comment: I am getting the price from csv. For example if input is 12 I get 35 instead of 40

Comment: In this code the pricecount for `12` is always `$price*1.15`. You should print the input and output values of the variables, then it will make more sense. Check the answers bellow.

Answer (score 2):

You have a series of `if` statements, but your last one is `if... else...`, so the else will override all other calculations.

You can rewrite it as a cascade if `if...elseif... else` so that you can reduce the comparisons but also ensure that only 1 gets executed...

```
$price = 12;
if ($price <=100)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.25+25;
}
elseif ($price <=300)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.25+20;
}
elseif ($price <=600)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.2+20;
}
elseif ($price<=1000)
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.2;
}
else
{
    $pricecount=$price*1.15;
}
echo $pricecount;
```

gives

```
40
```

Comment: Sorry. The result is the same.

Comment: Can you show what `$price` values are when you get the same results.

Comment: Sure. For example I get 35 instead of 40 if price<100

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

There may be different logic's to perform this task -

```
function test($price, $arr, $arr1, $val){
    foreach($price as $key => $p){
        if($val <= $p){
            $pricecount=$val*$arr[$key]+$arr1[$key];
            //echo $val.' '.$arr[$key].' '.$pricecount.' ';
            return $pricecount;
        }
    }
    return $val*1.15;
}

//here you can use your csv values
$price = [100, 300, 600, 1000];
$arr = [1.25, 1.25, 1.2, 1.2, 1.15];
$arr1 = [25, 20, 20, 0];

$pricecount = '';


$a = test($price, $arr, $arr1, 12);

print_r($a);
//This will give you answer 40
```

This is just a different way. Check to verify [answer](https://www.tehplayground.com/yyIVKrX8jQMYES71)

Thanks.

Comment: If you put 12 in this code you don't get any output.

Comment: You also always multiple by `$p` which isn't the price but the price break. I would also check what `((float)$arr[$key])` gives you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Answer edited. Check this answer verified - https://www.tehplayground.com/yyIVKrX8jQMYES71